# How to Make a Looping Discord Bot Task that is Invoked When a Message is Posted in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to write a discord bot that posts yeterday's Wordle solutions but I cannot seem to figure out how to get a task to be invoked by a message and then have that task loop. I tried to use a while loop but then the bot would only work for one server. Trying to use a looping task does not work either. Here is the code

```
import imp
import json
import requests
import discord
import os
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta
from discord.ext import tasks


client = discord.Client()
#channel_id_exists = False
#channel_id = 0


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!wordle_setup'):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send("Setting up...")
        channel_id = message.channel.id
        await wordle_guess(channel_id).start()


@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def wordle_guess(channel_id):

    message_channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)

    year = yesterday.year
    month = yesterday.month
    day = yesterday.day

    word_guess = json.loads(requests.get(
        "https://najemi.cz/wordle_answers/api/?day={0}&month={1}&year={2}".format(day, month, year)).text)["word"]
    await message_channel.send("Word guess for " + yesterday.isoformat() + " : " + word_guess + '\nhttps://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/' + word_guess)

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Either the bot gets stuck at setup, or the the task doesn't loop in 10 seconds, or the bot only works for one server. I use the setup command to prevent needing to hardcode the channel id into the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by wrapping the code in a client class and allowing the storage of multiple channel ids. The new code is shown here.

```
import asyncio
import imp
import json
import requests
import discord
import os
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta
from discord.ext import tasks
import threading

print("test!")


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    channel_id = []
    channel_id_exists = False

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(self))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('!wordle_setup'):
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("Setting up...")
            self.channel_id.append(message.channel.id)
            self.channel_id_exists = True

    @tasks.loop(seconds=3600*24)
    async def wordle_guess(self):
        if self.channel_id_exists:

            yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)

            year = yesterday.year
            month = yesterday.month
            day = yesterday.day

            for channel_id_iter in self.channel_id:
                message_channel = self.get_channel(channel_id_iter)
                word_guess = json.loads(requests.get(
                    "https://najemi.cz/wordle_answers/api/?day={0}&month={1}&year={2}".format(day, month, year)).text)["word"]
                await message_channel.send("Wordle guess for " + yesterday.isoformat() + " : " + word_guess + '\nhttps://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/' + word_guess)


client = MyClient()
client.wordle_guess.start()
client.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also launch a task from a command.
In my case, using the module interactions, I have a discord function that has to run every hour or when the command is triggered. There may be better solutions but this one worked for me.

```
from discord.ext import tasks
import interactions
...
bot = interactions.Client(bot_token,...)
...

# manually triggered command
@bot.command( name='sync_roles', ...)
async def command_sync_roles(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    global busy
    if busy: return
    bot._loop.create_task(sync_roles())

# scheduled job
@tasks.loop(hours=1)
async def cron_sync_roles():
    global busy
    if busy: return
    bot._loop.create_task(sync_roles())

# I use busy as a global variable to avoid double calls
busy = False
async def sync_roles():
    global busy
    busy = True
    ## Your code here
    busy = False

...
cron_sync_roles.start()
bot.start()
```